# Scraping pages that do not seem to have URLs

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to scrape these listings and provide more exposure for these job listings on a site that belongs to a client of mine. The issue is that I need to be able to link to the specific job listing in order for the job seeker to apply. [This is the page](http://mosaic.taleo.net/careersection/10203/jobsearch.ftl) I'm trying to save listing links from.

It would be ideal if I could save an address for the job seeker to click on to see the original listing and then apply.

1. What is this website doing to not feature a URL for these pages
2. Is it possible to provide a listing specific address
3. If that's possible how could I generate that address?

If I can't get a specific address I think I could get it so that the user clicks a link that triggers an internal script on my client's site which takes the listing ID and searches the site I found that listing on, and then redirects the user to that specific listing.

The downside to this is that the user will have to wait a little while depending on how far back the listing is on a directory. I could put some kind of progress bar with a pleasant "Searching for your listing! Thanks for being patient" message.

If I can avoid having to do this, though, that'd be great!

I'm using Nokogiri and Mechanize.

Comment: Yea mechanize allows for form submission. Thanks!

Comment: If you could write what you put here as an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you refer to appears to be generated by an Oracle product, so one would think they'd be willing to construct a web form properly (and with reference to accessibility concerns). They haven't, so it occurs to me that either their engineer was having a bad day, or they are deliberately making it (slightly) harder to scrape.

The reason your browser shows no `href` when you hover over those links is that there isn't one. What the page does instead is to use JavaScript to capture the click event, populate a POST form with some hidden values, and call the `submit` method programmatically. This can cause problems with screen-readers and other accessibility devices, as well as causing problems with the way in which back buttons have to re-submit the page.

The good news is that constructions of this kind can usually be scraped by creating a form yourself, either using a real one on a third party page, or via a crawler library. If you post the right values to the target URI, reverse-engineered from examining the page's script, the resulting document should be the "linked" page you expect.